# How to get the duration of an mp3 file

Tags: python-3.x, audio, mp3, duration

I tried many methods but did not get the exact length value of an mp3 file.

With moviepy:

```
audiofile = AudioFileClip(url)
print("duration moviepy: " + str(audiofile.duration))
```

I get result:

```
duration moviepy: 183.59
```

With mutagen:

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
audio = MP3(url)
print("duration mutagen: " + str(audio.info.length))
```

I received another value of duration:

```
duration mutagen: 140.93416666666667
```

Actual duration value when I open the file using windows media player: 2m49s

I don't know what happens to my audio file, I test a few files from the music website and still get the correct value.
[This is my audio file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11_hPe5FDbNWrxawrikXrWXpuNWTlUTjD/view)

Comment: The audio file you shared is 3:04

Comment: When you download the file it will show 2:49, I don't understand what's going on

Comment: That's strange. Right now I'm thinking that something is up with the frequency header in your file. Perhaps it's missing and different audio libraries / sources are coming up with different default frequencies to fill in the gaps.

Comment: The audio file linked has about 1,800 errors where an audio frame is followed by garbage, which amounts to roughly half of the entire file. So a time calculated from summing the duration of all audio frames should be about double that of a time estimated from the length of the file in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

try [pyxsox](https://github.com/rabitt/pysox)

I tried to use pysox to [the audio file which includes this question post](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11_hPe5FDbNWrxawrikXrWXpuNWTlUTjD/view)

note: pysox needs SOX cli.

how to use it is like this.

```
import sox
mp3_path = "YOUR STRANGE MP3 FILEPATH"
length = sox.file_info.duration(mp3_path)
print("duration sec: " + str(length))
print("duration min: " + str(int(length/60)) + ':' + str(int(length%60)))
```

results are

```
duration sec: 205.347982
duration min: 3:25
```

and the others information on that mp3 file's duration.

```
ID3 information => 2.49
mutagen => 2:20
pysox => 3:25
actural length => 3:26
```

mutagen seems just to read ID3 information.

Comment: Odd. The file doesn't contain a `TLE` or `TLEN` field in the ID3 tag, only a `TSSE` field. So it tells use `EncoderSettings = Lavf57.83.100` but tells us nothing about the length or duration of the audio.

Answer (score 1):

Using Mutagen

```
pip install mutagen
```

python:

```
import os
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

def convert_seconds(seconds):
    hours = seconds // 3600
    seconds %= 3600
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (hours, minutes, seconds)

path = "Your mp3 files floder."
total_length = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(path)):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            audio = MP3(os.path.join(root, file))
            length = audio.info.length
            total_length += length

hours, minutes, seconds = convert_seconds(total_length).split(":")
print("total duration: " + str(int(hours)) + ':' + str(int(minutes)) + ':' + str(int(seconds)))
```